# Add resources in appimage

Tags: c++, linux, executable, appimage

I am trying to create AppImage for a C++ application. I have few resources that I have to bundle, like shader files and fonts and images used in the application. They are put into a 'resources' folder.

I am using appimage-builder to generate the AppImage by following the guide [here](https://appimage-builder.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html).

When I run the AppRun executable, I get segmentation fault. I suspect it is because of not bundling the resources folder in AppRun.

Kindly help me in bundling the extra folders with appimage-builder.

Comment: It would be great if you cold provide some extra information related to the segmentation fault error in order to be able to give you some hints.

You can also check the [troubleshooting guide](https://appimage-builder.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/troubleshooting.html) for hints on how to debug your bundle.

Answer (score 2):

To bundle additional resources into an AppImage is enough to just copy them into the AppDir before calling appimage-builder. Or add the copy instructions in the [recipe script section](https://appimage-builder.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/version_1.html#script)

In the application code you can look for the APPDIR environment variable which will be set at runtime. This variable will hold the path to the AppDir at runtime.